# App layout using Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am creating an Electron app with React and using Semantic UI for the layout. I basically want a UI that completely fills the viewport, a menu, preferably a toolbar on top and other contents below it. The content area should fill all the remaining area after the toolbar is placed on top.

I am not a css guru and trying to use Semantic UI React components to achieve this but got really lost in all these different layout examples and unfortunately not a single one worked for me.

Can someone please direct me to a pen or share a very simple layout example to get me started?

Thanks.

Comment: You're asking a lot of the community here. We have to make some pretty big assumptions about what you are looking for without even providing something. Even providing the CLOSEST you got to the layout you want would be better than nothing. You're effectively asking for someone to build your layout from scratch.

Comment: I'm just asking for someone to let me in the right direction to build a grid that fills the page, has two rows in which the second row fills the area remained from the first row. I guess that's really easy to do with flexbox but not so easy for me to build with Semantic-React. I'm not asking someone to build a full layout for me.